# jQuery show a number of list items, fade them out then show some more

Tags: jquery

I've got an ordered list of thumbnail images. I'm trying to figure out how to display say - 9 of these, then have them fade out and display the following 9, etc etc. using jQuery.

There will be a lot of images, so I'll need the function to keep on truckin...

I'd be very grateful for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two pieces of code for you:

```
var show = 9;
var current = show - 1;
var length;

var gallery = $('#gallery');

var galleryItems = gallery.children('li');
length = galleryItems.length;

setInterval(function(){
    current = (current+1)%60;

    galleryItems.eq(current).slideDown();
    galleryItems.eq(current - show).slideUp();
}, 3000);
```

This would shift the whole list upwards one item at a time. See: http://jsfiddle.net/VL646/1/

---

```
var show = 9;
var current = 0;
var length;

var gallery = $('#gallery');

var galleryItems = gallery.children('li');
length = galleryItems.length;

setInterval(function(){
    for(var i = current; i < (current+show); i++){
        galleryItems.eq(i).fadeOut(300, function(){
            var idx = (galleryItems.index(this) + show) % length;
            galleryItems.eq(idx).fadeIn(300);
        });
    }

    current += show;
    if(current > length) current = 0;
}, 4000);
```

And this would fade in and fade out groups of items together. See: http://jsfiddle.net/DtFwH/

The main thing to keep in mind here is the `setInterval()` function, which keeps running a function over and over again, and the `.eq(n)` function, which gets the n<sup>th</sup> element of the current jQuery object.

Comment: Lovely! Any chance you might be able to pause the effect if you hover over a <li>?! Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = $temp = $("img");
for(var i=0; i<$a.length; i++) {
      $temp = $a.hide(); 
      $temp.slice(i * 9, 9).fadeIn();
      setTimeout('',1000);
}
```

may be this one will work

Comment: It won't. You've got the concept of `setTimeout` wrong. Here, check the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 1):

@Yi - a HUGE thanks for this!!

here's the code I've used

```
var show = 15;
var current = 0;
var gallery = $('ul#img-list');
var galleryItems = gallery.children('li');
var length = galleryItems.length;
gallery.children('li:gt(14)', this).hide();

setInterval(function(){
for(var i = current; i < (current+show); i++){
    galleryItems.eq(i).fadeOut(600, function(){
    var idx = (galleryItems.index(this) + show) % length;
    galleryItems.eq(idx).fadeIn(900);
  });
}
current += show;
     if(current > length) current = 0;
}, 5000);
```

Which works a treat!! I wonder - if it's not too much to ask! - if you might be able to enlighten me with how I could pause the effect when the user mouses-over an image?

Massive thanks again!

Comment: Well, two things: First, you shouldn't post this as a answer, since this is really a repetition of my answer. On this site, you should mark an answer as correct if it solves your problem, while if you need to change/add new things to your problem you can use comments, such as this one.

Comment: To answer your question, remember that [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) returns an ID which can be used to stop the function from repeating. Combine that with the jQuery [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks Yi - I'll do my best! Sorry for posting in the wrong place, I'm new to the site and I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Yi - Hmm, I've been playing around with this for a while now, but my jQuery just isn't up to the job! Any ideas on how to pause the effect (the 2nd bit of code you gave me is ideal) on mouseover?